# WatiN permissions problem when eval javascript code

Tags: watin

My environment is: WindowXP, IE8, VS2008, WatiN-2.0.20

When i try to execute the follow code:

```
IE _browser = new IE();
_browser.GoTo(_url);
_browser.Eval("alert('hello!');");
```

I get the following error:

Message:

```
"Access denied. (Exception of HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
```

Source:

```
"Microsoft.mshtml"
```

Partial StackTrace

```
   in WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEUtils.RunScript(String scriptCode, String language, IHTMLWindow2 window)
   in WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEDocument.RunScript(String scriptCode, String language)
   in WatiN.Core.Document.RunScript(String scriptCode, String language)
   in WatiN.Core.Document.RunScript(String javaScriptCode)
   in WatiN.Core.Document.Eval(String javaScriptCode)
```

I know is about a premissions problem but i don't know how solve it.
Any ideas about this issue.

Comment: removed tag `watir` since the question is not related to Watir

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try turning off IE's protected mode or add your site to trusted zone.

Comment: The real problem was that I thought I was doing tests against a server in my machine but I was really pointing to the deployment machine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It did stoped the exception but `browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN")` doesn't type anything.