# I can not typetext in WatiN

Tags: watin

i want type text in a textbox that linked to a database and return subject of typed text code.

ex:

when i click on that textbox and try typetext visual studio get error.

i dont want use value fot this textbox.

```
browser.textfield(find.byid("textcode")).typetext ("12345");
```

this is get error

```
browser.textfield(find.byid("textcode")).value = "12345";
```

this is worked,  but in my automation i need type text no put value.

Comment: What is the error?  And what difference does it make if you "type" the text vs. just setting it in the DOM?

Comment: error is RunScript failed  when program trying to typetext in textbox,, the system access denied error apeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RunScript error can happen when the site is untrusted. I ran into this exact error today when trying to run tests against a file on the local filesystem.  Making the page part of the IE trusted sites fixed the problem.

More details here:  [Watin integration test failing with System.UnauthorizedAccessException when executing javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472979/watin-integration-test-failing-with-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-when-exec)